# Error when trying to plot a folium

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

I am working on my assigment in Mathematica and I get this weird error when trying to plot the graph (folium) with tangent lines.

`` Error (Coordinate {12 $CellContext`t1/(1 + $CellContext`t1^3), 12 $CellContext`t1^2/(1 + $CellContext`t1^3)} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form) ``

Here is my original code:

```
(*Find values of t for vertical tangent lines*)
Solve[D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t] == Infinity, t, Reals];

(*Find values of t for horizontal tangent lines*)
Solve[D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t] == 0, t, Reals]

(*Find values of t for horizontal tngent lines*)
ht = Solve[{D[y[t], t] == 0, t != -1, t != 1}, t, Reals, 
  MaxExtraConditions -> 
   All] (*Exclude -1 and 1 because we get a floaitng point exception*)

(*Plot the folium and the tangent lines*)
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}], 
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
   Line[({x[#], y[#]} & /@ {-1, 0, 1}) /. t -> #] &, 
   Table[Line[{{-10, y[t]}, {10, y[t]}}], {t, t /. ht}]}]
```

And here is my code when I broke it down to try and figure out what's happening. I had to change some stuff because I am not very familiar with mapping

```
x[t_] := (12 t)/(1 + t^3)
y[t_] := (12 t^2)/(1 + t^3)

pplot = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];

tVals = t /. Solve[D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t] == 0, t, Reals];
tVals

tangent = 
  Plot[Evaluate@
    Table[y'[tVals[[i]]]*(x - x[tVals[[i]]]) + y[tVals[[i]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[tVals]}], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Dashed];

Show[pplot, tangent, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Your second code works for me. The first code works if I get rid of `Line[({x[#], y[#]} & /@ {-1, 0, 1}) /. t -> #] &`.  I don't get your errors.  Perhaps try quitting the kernel and re-executing.

Comment: That fixed it thank you. Would you say that this line : ```Line[({x[#], y[#]} & /@ {-1, 0, 1}) /. t -> #] &``` wasn't necessary?

Comment: No it's not necessary. (In fact, it causes an error for me, but a different one than you got for some reason.)

Comment: Is it this one:  Function is not a Graphics primitive or directive? I was battling that one 2 hours ago :/

Comment: Yep. It comes from the `&` outside the closing `]` of `Line[...`, which makes a `Function`. Nothing is plugged into it, so it stays a `Function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- We can solve the equation which `{x'[t],y'[t]}` parallel to the direction `{0,1}` to find the vertical tangent line.

```
dir={0,1};
Solve[Det[{{x'[t], y'[t]}, dir}] == 0, t, Reals]
```

```
x[t_] := (12 t)/(1 + t^3)
y[t_] := (12 t^2)/(1 + t^3)
dir = {0, 1};
sol = Solve[Det[{{x'[t], y'[t]}, dir}] == 0, t, Reals];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {{AbsolutePointSize[8], Red, 
    Point[{x[t], y[t]}] /. sol}, {Green, Dashed, 
    InfiniteLine[{x[t], y[t]}, dir] /. sol}}]
```

[image]

- There no vertical tangent line at the original point `{0,0}` since only when `t->Infinity` the curve go back to the original `{0,0}`. We can see this by the animation.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -20, 20}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  MeshStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Red}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{s}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  Epilog -> {Dashed, 
    Arrow[{{x[s], y[s]}, {x[s], y[s]} + {x'[s], y'[s]}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> 15], {s, -.6, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: I got a different solution. When trying to get a/the vertical tangent line/s you would set x'[t] equal to zero correct? I did that by using the Solve keyword ```Solve[D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t] == Infinity, t, Reals]``` In my case I got only one solution t-> 0. Could you please explain to me how our answers differ? Thank you!

Comment: @Jakob For the expression `D[y[t], t]/D[x[t],t]`, Mathematica will exclude the case when `D[x[t]==0`, but if we use the form `{D[x[t],t],D[y[t], t]}` ,there are not such restrict.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Thank you so much

Comment: The problem with tangency at the origin is a defect of the parametrization, which does not cover the complete folium (unless one parametrizes over $t \in \Bbb R \Bbb P^1$).

Answer (score 3):

`Solve[{eqn, Dt@eqn, Dt[x] == 0 || Dt[y] == 0} /. sub, {x, y, dx, dy}, Reals]` contains the horizontal (`Dt[y] == 0`) and vertical (`Dt[x] == 0`) tangent lines. We just have to filter them out.

```
x[t_] := (12 t)/(1 + t^3)
y[t_] := (12 t^2)/(1 + t^3)

eqn = Eliminate[{x == x[t], y == y[t]}, t];
Clear[x, y];
sub = {Dt[x] -> dx, Dt[y] -> dy}; (* change diffs to variables *)
tangents = Quiet@ (* tangent solutions cause messages *)
 Solve[{eqn, Dt@eqn, Dt[x] == 0 || Dt[y] == 0} /. sub,
      {x, y, dx, dy}, Reals] //
    (* Filter out tangent solutions *)
    Select[MatchQ[{x -> _, y -> _, dx | dy -> _}]] //
   (* Convert to equations *)
   Cases[# /. Reverse /@ sub, (v : x | y -> v0_) :> 
      v == Normal@v0 /; FreeQ[v0, v], 2] & //
  FullSimplify

(* tangents
  {y == 0, x == 0, y == 4 2^(2/3), x == 4 2^(2/3)} 
*)

ContourPlot[Evaluate@Prepend[tangents, eqn],
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed}]
```

[image]

---

Inspired by @kglr's `displayFunction`:

```
grad = D[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract, {{x, y}}];
displayFunction = 
  Module[{pts = Cases[Normal@#, Point[x_] :> x, All]},
    Show[#, 
     Prolog -> {Opacity[.2, ColorData[97]@1], Opacity[1], 
       Dashed, Thick,
       MapThread[Style]@{InfiniteLine[#, 
            Cross[grad /. Thread[{x, y} -> #]]] & /@ pts, 
         ColorData[97] /@ Range[2, 1 + Length@pts]}}]] &;
mf = Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[Times @@ grad]];
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn,
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 MeshFunctions -> {1 &, mf},
 Mesh -> {{0}, {0}},
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction]

(* plot looks like the above one *)
```

I don't know why the first `MeshFunction` is ignored (if you remove the seemingly pointless `1 &`, the code won't find the tangent lines). A bug, perhaps, unless someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of the options  [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html):

```
displayFunction =
 Module[{br = BoundingRegion @ Cases[Normal @ #, Point[x_] :> x, All]}, 
  Show[#, Prolog -> {Opacity[.2, ColorData[97] @ 1], br, 
      Opacity[1], Dashed, Thick, 
      MapThread[Style] @ {InfiniteLine @@@ MeshPrimitives[br, 1], 
         ColorData[97] /@ Range[2, 5]}}]] &;


ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 MeshFunctions -> {x'[#3]  y'[#3] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future that might run into the same issue, here is the code (with the help from experts on this platform) that works:

```
x[t_] := (12 t)/(1 + t^3)
y[t_] := (12 t^2)/(1 + t^3)
```

Vertical Tangents

```
dir = {0, 1};
sol = Solve[Det[{{x'[t], y'[t]}, dir}] == 0, t, Reals];
```

Horizontal Tangents

```
sol2 = Solve[{D[y[t], t] == 0, t != -1, t != 1}, t, Reals, 
  MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

Plot

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Brown, 
  PlotLabel -> "Folium of Descartes"], 
 Epilog -> {Blue, Dashed, 
   Table[Line[{{-10, y[t]}, {10, y[t]}}], {t, 
     t /. ht}], {AbsolutePointSize[6], Blue, 
    Point[{x[t], y[t]}] /. sol2}, {AbsolutePointSize[6], Blue, 
    Point[{x[t], y[t]}] /. sol}, {Blue, Dashed, 
    InfiniteLine[{x[t], y[t]}, dir] /. sol}}]
```

Comment: We can set `dir={1,0}` or other directions to get another tangent line.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom function as option setting for `MeshStyle`:

```
meshStyle = (m |-> {Dashed,  Gray, ##2, 
      ReplaceAll[Point[c_] :> (p |-> InfiniteLine[p, #]) /@ c]@ m}) &;

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -100, 100},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 MeshFunctions -> {x'[#3] &, y'[#3] &},
 Mesh -> {{0, 10^-4}, {0}},
 MeshStyle -> {meshStyle[{0, 1}], meshStyle[{1, 0}]},
 DisplayFunction -> Normal]
```

[image]